# Recieving null pointer exception while using selenium pagefactory

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pageobjects

I am using selenium page factory. And while using any of the WebElements, I am receiving null pointer exception.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.PagesUsingPageFactory.AddNewCustomerUsingPF;
import com.PageswithoutPageFactory.HomePage;
import com.PageswithoutPageFactory.InvokeBrowserSettings;
import com.PageswithoutPageFactory.LoginPage;

public class CreateNewCustomerNegative {
    WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public void TC_02() throws Exception{
        HomePage hompg = new HomePage(driver);
        AddNewCustomerUsingPF newcust = new AddNewCustomerUsingPF(driver);

        LoginPage loginpage = new LoginPage(driver);


    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Chinmay\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            InvokeBrowserSettings invoke = new InvokeBrowserSettings();
            driver = invoke.invokeBrowser("chrome", Constant.URL);


        loginpage.SignIntoAppWithValidUsrPwd(driver);

        //verify home page displayed after valid credentials
        hompg.validateHomePageLogo(driver);
        hompg.validateManagerButton(driver);
        hompg.validatenewCustomerButton(driver);

        hompg.clickNewCustomer(driver);
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'New Customer')]")).click();

        //check if add new customer tab is present
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Add New Customer')]")).isDisplayed(), "Add new customer option is not visible");
        //check if customer name textbox is present     
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.name("name")).isDisplayed(), "Customer name text box is not presernt");

        //name field blank validation
        System.out.println("driver=" + driver); 
        newcust.typeCustomerName("");
}
}
```

`
Whenever I am using pagefactory for identifying objects, it throws nullpointer exception.
The weird thing is the page factory works for first java file  test case, when I use same page factory in another java file, it always fails with nullpointer exception.
I saw some solution on stackoverflow [Selenium java.lang.NullPointerException with PageFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185378/selenium-java-lang-nullpointerexception-with-pagefactory)

However, it did not work for me.
I tried initializing page object in my test case and also in my page object script. However, neither of it worked for me.

Here is the code for page factory :

```
package com.PagesUsingPageFactory;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class AddNewCustomerUsingPF {
public WebDriver driver;

    public AddNewCustomerUsingPF(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver=driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);


    }

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//p[contains(text(),'Add New Customer')]")
    public WebElement addNewCustomerLabel;

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//input[@type='text'][@name='name']")
    public WebElement customerNameTxtField;

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//a[contains(text(),'New Customer')]")
    public WebElement newCustomerButton;



    public void typeCustomerName(String name) throws Exception {
        customerNameTxtField.sendKeys(name);
    }


}
```

Please help me out. I am debigging this issue since more than a week and not able to find the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NullpointerException in Selenium when using SendKeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968344/nullpointerexception-in-selenium-when-using-sendkeys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see here

```
  WebDriver driver;
@Test
public void TC_02() throws Exception{
    HomePage hompg = new HomePage(driver);
```

i hope in HomePage, there is code to initialize driver, that why it is working. then you are passing driver which is not initialized

```
WebDriver driver;
```

So, you may need to try to collect driver from Homepage and then pass to other pages also.

Answer (score 1):

As murail said, the driver is not initialized when page factory is intialized. It is passing driver as null.

Change page factory initialization after driver initialization as given below.

```
public class CreateNewCustomerNegative {
    WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public void TC_02() throws Exception{
       //Initialize the driver first
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Chinmay\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
       InvokeBrowserSettings invoke = new InvokeBrowserSettings();
       driver = invoke.invokeBrowser("chrome", Constant.URL);

       //Initialize page factory 
        HomePage hompg = new HomePage(driver);
        AddNewCustomerUsingPF newcust = new AddNewCustomerUsingPF(driver);
        LoginPage loginpage = new LoginPage(driver);

        loginpage.SignIntoAppWithValidUsrPwd(driver);
```